# Open python module/file as new instance in new click button without saving the original file in memory

Tags: python, tkinter, module

When I create my own module in a python script I can execute another file upon button click from the first window.

For illustration:

```
import module
def openbutton():
   module.window.create()
r = tk.Tk()
refresh_file_list = tk.Button(r, text='refresh file list', width=30, command= openbutton), height=grid_average)
refresh_file_list.grid(row=rows, column=columns)
```

When this is executed the module is already in memory and no longer pulls the file after clicking the button, meaning whatever I alter in module the changes are only made when I restart the program, which is annoying in a program with a lot of steps, or if I simply want to try out various things before commiting.

How do I make python run the script anew?

Comment: Does `def openbutton(): import module; module.window.create()` (reimport again) what you want to achieve? And if not, why?

Comment: @Claudio It is more like I want to open a separate window and output data generated in the first window in the second window. Like for example the new window shows the data of files being renamed/sorted etc. in that window while the function is running in the first or another script. How would I call a variable from the other window and output the data generated in the other how do I write that?

module.window.button.insert(0,"whatever") or anything else I try does not work.

Comment: @ Brecht Corbeel : haven't tested it yet, but if you define in your module a variable as *global*, this variable should be then available in that module even if it comes from the 'main' script using this module and the code of the  module shouldn't raise an error that you use a variable before defining it.